# Programmatically enable data connection every 30 minutes?

Tags: automation

How can I enable (WiFi and Data) connection every 30 minutes, then keep it active for 2 minutes (time required to get any notifications), and then disable the connection again?

Are there any solutions besides Tasker?

Comment: Plenty. Best known for that is probably *JuiceDefender*. Llama and other automating-tools will handle that as well.

Comment: [DS battery Saver Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rootuninstaller.batrsaver&hl=en) has the exact functionality, in case you would like to see an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to pay for Tasker, use the free alternative [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate). It has similar functionality and can automate the same things.

Comment: While Automate is "free", it follows the "freemium" model, so it does have in-app purchases.

Comment: @Ryan Yes, but automating the Wi-Fi as OP was asking for can be done without any purchase, for free.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Android bot maker](http://www.maketecheasier.com/automate-android-phone-with-android-bot-maker/) which can automate taps at particular co-ordinates..swipes etc..  But root access is needed for this app...